# Nextjs13 typescript dynamic routing is returning an error "XML Parsing Error: no root element found Location"

Tags: typescript, axios, next.js13

My team leader switch a project to nextjs13 and I am implementing payment integration that runs on a dynamic route inside the app directory `/api/[verify]/route.ts`. This is a standalone POS solution not integrated into the main app. So I have brought over the the files from nextjs12 or whatever and retrofitted it to next13 but it looks like I have not completed it inside postman I am getting an error `405 method not allowed`. Please have a look at the code and help.

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import axios from 'axios';

type Data = {
  success: boolean;
  data?: Object;
};

const apiKey =
  process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL === 'http://localhost:3000/'
    ? (process.env.NEXT_PAYSTACK_SECRET_TEST_KEY as string)
    : (process.env.NEXT_PAYSTACK_SECRET_LIVE_KEY as string);

export default async function GET(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  { params }: { params: { reference: string } },
  resp: NextApiResponse<Data>
) {
  const { reference } = params;

  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://api.paystack.co/transaction/verify/${reference}`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
      },
    });
    const { data } = response;
    resp.status(200).json({ success: true, data: data.data });
  } catch (error) {
    resp.status(400).json({ success: false });
  }
}
```